# Passing a list or tuple of unknown length to pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

This question is essentially two parts: how does Pathlib handle an unknown number of path segments as arguments and is it possible to pass a list or tuple into the constructor?

The documentation for the `Path` class is as follows:

```
class pathlib.Path(*pathsegments)
```

I know it will accept a variable number of arguments, so I figured it may also check the type and then expand a list or tuple as appropriate. Testing has shown it doesn't do that, however:

```
import pathlib

parts = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
p = pathlib.Path(parts)
```

which results in:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

The same thing happens with a tuple. How can I use Pathlib to construct a path out of an unknown number of path segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it like this:

```
p = pathlib.Path(*parts)
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the part I was missing.